# Not Include Decimals In Sentence Count

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is not include, in my sentence count in a paragraph, decimals values that will appear in the paragraph.

For example, I have a situation where in my paragraphs, they may contain decimals like "0.1344" or codes like "5.00153.09". How can I not include these periods in my sentence count?

Comment: The general approach to solve any software development problem is to formalise it. So, start with the formal definition of the "sentence" term.

Comment: Try to explain it a bit more and give more information like what you are trying to achieve, your sample data, what you did so far....

Comment: my guess is you got a paragraph say like this 'My first sentence. Then a 1.2 in second sentence.' You want to get the sentence count 2, but the 1.2 made you get a 3 rather than a 2? if thats the case,a simple way is to split by '. ', add a space after the '.'

Comment: What about abbreviations like 'Mr. Duck'?

Answer (score 2):

I think a generic method to count sentences is a complex thing to do. But, depending on the input you are trying to parse, you can count the number of sentences by the number of dots not followed by a digit.

Let's say:

1 - all sentences end with a period (.)

2 - the only other time a dot appears is in a code (5.00153.09) or decimal (23.22).

3 - there are not sentences in which the period is just followed by a digit. eg. `"I am not a sentence.1"`

Then you could count the number of sentences using regular expression, this way:

```js
const count = (str) => {
  const re = /\.(?![0-9])/g
  return ((str || '').match(re) || []).length
}

const str = "Sentence 5.00153.09 has a code. 0.1344 starts the second sentence.\nThird sentence is a number too 530.1344.\nAnd a fourth plain sentence here."


console.log(`'${str}' has ${count(str)} sentences`)
```

The magic here is the regular expression `\.(?![0-9])`, it uses a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to define "a dot that is not followed by a digit"